# how to check memory usage of an android app using apache cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-memory

Hi I want to check the memory usage of the application and processor of the application.Is that possible in android application which is developed in apache cordova using javascript,HTML5,CSS3.Please suggest some solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the method I use to monitor the memory usage of my Cordova apps.

1. Start your Cordova app on your Android system.
2. Open the Stock Settings App that is bundled with Android.
3. Navigate to the Apps tab.
4. You should see a list of applications. On the top of the screen (this will differ from device to device), there should be a scroll-able bar that says "Downloaded". Scroll right until it says "Running".
5. Look for your app in the list of running apps. Tap it to see information, including memory usage.

Explanation with gifs: [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/See-What-Apps-Are-Currently-Running-on-Android)

NOTE: Sometimes you may have to hit "SHOW CACHED PROCESSES" at the top to see Cordova apps in the list.

As for processor usage,

1. Open the Settings App.
2. Navigate to Developer Tools
3. Enable them and under the 'Monitoring' section, check 'Show CPU usage'.

NOTE: The CPU Usage overlay can be a bit confusing, monitor it carefully!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but i want it using programatically

Comment: Oh, then no, as far as I know, there isn't, at least without writing your own plugin for it. Sorry!